# Como hago para que los datos suplidores.id y suplidores.uuid vengan separados

Tags: javascript

Necesito que los datos suplidores.id y suplidores.uuid que estan en vengan separados pero que sigan estando en values.

```
             let options = [];
            _.forEach(suplidores, function (suplidores) {
                options.push({
                    text: suplidores.nombre,
                    value: suplidores.id,
                    uuid: suplidores.uuid,
                });
            });
```

Mas abajo estoy haciendo esto

```
             callback: function callback(result) {
                    if (result) {
                      console.log(result)
                        myresolve(result);
                    }
                }
```

Y result es el contenido de value, el cual esta viniendo como un array de los dos valores juntos, pero necesito que lleguen los valores por separadp

Comment: Podes ser mas especifico? no se entiende bien que quieres, a que te refieres con "vengan separados"? ten en cuenta que nosotros no conocemos el contexto de lo que estas haciendo y el resto del codigo.

Comment: Mas abajo estoy haciendo esto

callback: function callback(result) {
                    if (result) {
                      console.log(result)
                        myresolve(result);
                    }
                }

y result es el contenido de value, el cual esta viniendo como un array de los dos valores juntos, pero necesito que lleguen los valores por separadp

Comment: y separalos... no se entiende bien cual es el problema, tal vez falta mucho mas contexto??

Comment: Si, poruqe al hacer console log, llegan los dos valores juntos

Comment: Hola @TomásGutiérrez, todavia no se entiende que buscas obtener. Presioná [edit] y agrega un ejemplo de lo que llega y lo que quisieras obtener. Tratá de ser mas claro, ¿que se ejecuta primero? ¿que es `myresolve`? Nosotros solo vemos lo que compartís.